# SQLite: insert with select

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can anyone tell me why the following SQL refuses to insert more than 1 result (using sqlite3)? And how to make it insert all distinct values from the select port_shipment?
 
The cargo table in this database contains more than 2000 distinct values for port_shipment, but I tried several versions of the insert-command which resulted always in only 1 value inserted.

```
create table port (
    port_ID integer  not null  primary key,
    port_description text unique collate nocase,
    port_name text,
    country text,
    lat text,
    lon text
)

insert or ignore into port (port_ID, port_description)
values (null, (SELECT port_shipment FROM cargo))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `values` statement is not needed with `select`.  Try this:

```
insert or ignore into port (port_ID, port_description) 
    SELECT NULL, port_shipment
    FROM cargo
```